# Using linked models in arrary to filter names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Users have one profile, and profiles belong to users.

I'm trying to make a query where searching a user list, and I can search the names which exist in the user's profiles.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@user_list = User.where(:company_id => current_user.company.id)
  .joins(:profile).where("profile.first_name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

This doesn't work, but I'm not really sure where to go from here?

Comment: please, no "doesn't work"s, show the error/wrong result/whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You didn't write the error message or the database table, but i'm guessing that as a rails convention, the table is called `profiles` and not `profile`
2. You should scope by company instead of query by id in the user model

Together:

```
@user_list = current_user.company.users.
     joins(:profile).where("profiles.first_name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

try `User.includes(:profile)` instead of joins, and check the resulting sql query in the log. If it does not work, show us the resulting sql.